# Heap Memory Exhaustion while processing >10GB Data

Tags: spring-boot, jvm, out-of-memory

My REST API ( Spring-Boot 2.7) is supposed to fetch 20 Million Records from DB and send the response back to UI ( Angular 6) . The overall data size reaches to cross 10GB.

This results into Heap Outofmemory error. JVM Xms and XmX are set to 15GB .

Currently am fetching data from DB in batches but ultimately it has to be stored in an ArrayList , which is where JVM memory get exhausted .

Can someone tell me another approach to overcome this situation , as I can not add more memory to JVM

Comment: can you use pagination in front end because it usually not a good practice to send 20 million records as response ?

Comment: Don't store it in an array list. Instead send it out directly to the client in a streaming fashion. Storing all that in a list won't work. As you first have your objects, then that needs to be serialized to JSON. So the amount of memory needed is going to be massive twice or maybe even four times the amount of data you actually have.

Comment: @ManojKrishna Pagination is not an option , as its a report cum charting that need to be done on frontend , hence require whole data together .

Comment: @M.Deinum For the above same reason , streaming like websocket couldn't be used . The report is to be generated on backend that is one use case and other one is to have charts plotted on UI. Can you please elaborate more , if you think streaming can still be a solution .

Comment: Where did I state websockets? You can stream with events or streaming json as well. Also sending 10gb data to the frontend to generate a report on the frontend is also not really going to work imho. That will be terrible slow.

Comment: Even if we assume that the frontend can handle that amount of data on the client when even the server can’t handle it: why do you assume that the fact that the frontend has to keep everything in memory implies that the server has to hold it in memory? And which aspect dictates that it has to be an `ArrayList`?

Comment: @Holger Would really appreciate if you could help me with a solution .